# How to include nugget dependencies for a .dll assembly reference

Tags: visual-studio, .net-6.0

I have a project which I've built (call it "projectA") that generates a .dll "projectA.dll". I add this projectA.dll as an assembly reference to another project (call it "projectB"). All is working fine however projectA has some nugget packages that it relies upon. Everything builds fine but at runtime I encounter an error when one of the nugget packages that projectA.dll relies upon is used (the exception is thrown in the source code at that particular point).

Is there any way to include these nugget dependencies within the dll file so that the .dll is purely self contained?